# Display a multi image(array) name from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My problem is how to display the array image from database. I called that array image because when I uploaded that image I'm using an array to do upload to database.

I'm using this code to insert the file name to database

```
public function multipost()
{
    $filepath = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data('file_name'); 

    $filenames = '';

    foreach($filepath as $a) {
        $filenames .= $a['file_name'].",";
    }
    $filenames = rtrim($filenames,',');


    $db_data = array(
        'pic_id'=> NULL,
        'ad_pic'=> $filenames,
    );
    $this->db->insert('technical_slide_img', $db_data);
}
```

That result to

[image]

As you can see the **ad_pic** column has the value of `1.jpg,2.jpg`.
if I'm using like this

```
<?php foreach ($this->header_model->getalldata() as $row) {
        $image_arr = explode("/", $row->image); 
        $image_name = end($image_arr);
 echo base_url().'images/'.$image_name;
} ?>
```

to display that image. Is there any way to display that images? Or do I need to separate that 2 images into row?

Comment: Any reason why you're using `explode('/')` instead of `explode(',')` since you want to split the string by the commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
  <?php foreach ($this->header_model->getalldata() as $row) {
    $image_arr = explode("/", $row->image); 
    $image_name = end($image_arr);
    echo base_url().'images/'.$image_name;
 } ?>
```

with

```
<?php 
foreach ($this->header_model->getalldata() as $row) 
{
  $image_arr = explode(",", $row->ad_pic); 
  foreach($image_arr as $image_name) 
  {
    echo base_url().'images/'.$image_name .'<br />';
  }
 } 
?>
```

Comment: And try replacing **that's not working right?** with error generated.

Comment: sir it works but only the last filename instead of all filename is there any way to get that name 1 by 1?

Comment: @MGBC Edited as per your need. try now.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your database table image is saved with comma `,` and you are exploding it with slash `/` . So i think you have to replace `/` with `,` in your explode function.

```
<?php foreach ($this->header_model->getalldata() as $row) {
    $image_arr = explode(",", $row->image); 
    $image_name = end($image_arr);
    echo base_url().'images/'.$image_name;
 } ?>
```

Comment: sir, when I replace that into comma, only the last filename(2.jpg) was displayed not all the filename.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
    $image_arr = explode(",", $data_user->image);
    foreach($image_arr as $image_name) 
    {?>
        <img style="width:5em;"src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$image_name?>" class="img-reponsive thumbnail">
        <!-- echo base_url().'images/'.$image_name .'<br />'; -->
    <?php } 
?>
```